# Java работа с Timer (Circle)

Tags: java

Начинаю изучать Java.

Пример: нужно чтобы картинка (круг) доходил до границы окошка и возвращался назад. В одну сторону у меня вроде получилось,  в другую сторону как его вернуть не знаю.

Сам код:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.imageio.*;
import javax.swing.*;
public class Proj {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    myFrame o = new myFrame();

    }

}

class myFrame extends JFrame{
    public myFrame() {
    myPanel p =new myPanel();
    Container c = getContentPane();
    c.add(p);
    setBounds(0,0,800,600);
    setVisible(true);
    }   
}

class myPanel extends JPanel {
    private Image img;
    private int x=0, y=0;
    private Timer t1,t2;
    public myPanel() {
         t1= new Timer(5, new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {
                x++;
                repaint();
            }
        });
        t1.start();
        try {
            img = ImageIO.read(new File("./cir.png"));
        }
        catch(IOException exp) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error!");
        }
        t2 =new Timer(10, new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {
                if((x+img.getWidth(null))>=790) {
                t1.stop();

            }       
            }
        });
    }   
    public void paintComponent (Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawImage(img, x, y,50,50,null);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
package main;

import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class Proj {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        new Proj().new MyFrame();
    }

    class MyFrame extends JFrame{
        public MyFrame() throws IOException {
            MyPanel p =new MyPanel();
            Container c = getContentPane();
            c.add(p);
            setBounds(0,0,800,600);
            setVisible(true);
        }
    }

    class MyPanel extends JPanel {
        private Image img;
        private int x=0, y=0;
        private Timer t1,t2;
        private int direction = 1;
        public MyPanel() throws IOException {
            loadImage();
             t1= new Timer(5, new ActionListener() {
                 public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {
                     x += direction;

                     if((x+img.getWidth(null))>=790)
                         direction = -1;

                     repaint();
                 }
             });
             t1.start();

        }

        private void loadImage() throws IOException {
            ImageIcon ii = new ImageIcon("C:/Users/Николай/eclipse-workspace/Proj/src/main/cir.png");
            img = ii.getImage();
        }

        public void paintComponent (Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.drawImage(img, x, y,null);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное!